# Is it fine to use jpa repositories and hibernate(calling queries using criteria,HQL) in the same project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Is it fine to use jpa repositories and hibernate in the same application..i.e. using CRUDRepositories,JPARepositories etc..,EntityManager and SessionFactory in same application.

Comment: Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand this correctly, you are asking if it is fine to use repositories and hibernate in the same project.

[JPA is a specification](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html), i.e. rules on how persistence API should be implemented.

[Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) is a library (set of libraries if you want to be precise) which follows the JPA specification and provides its own implementation of it. When you are using hibernate, you are automatically following most of the JPA specification. Hibernate additionally provides some extra functionalities.

If you choose to use the extra functionalities then porting to another kind of data store which hibernate does not support might be a challenge. Most [common relational databases are supported](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases2) by default.

I think in that case you would need to change a lot of your design anyway. So go ahead and use Hibernate as you see fit.